# Jboss CDI with RestEasy

Tags: jboss, cdi, resteasy, jboss-eap-6

I get the following exception, when i try to use cdi in resteasy application

```
JBWEB000287: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate InjectorFactory implementation. 

    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:154) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap.contextInitialized(ResteasyBootstrap.java:28) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)


Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiInjectorFactory
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:364) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:146) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.7.Final-redhat-2.jar:2.3.7.Final-redhat-2]
    ... 12 more
```

I am using JBoss EAP 6.2.  Resteasy version is 2.3.7.Final which is bundled with Jboss.  I have beans.xml under WEB-INF. Kindly help me in this regard.

Comment: Is RESTEasy by change bundled in your deployment?

Comment: Yeah also please provide some more info - you mention a WAR, but what libs are going in your WAR?  Do you have resteasy/weld in there?

Comment: No. I don't have resteasy in WAR as resteasy is already available in Jboss. I don't have weld as well